# How to debug a DLL called from a DLL in Delphi

Tags: delphi, debugging, dll

Let's say I have an EXE named A, which loads a DLL named B, which in turn loads another DLL named C.
All of these three are written in Delphi.  I have the source for all three.

If I want to debug DLL B, I have no problem.  I go to Run|Parameters and enter A.EXE as the host. 
When I click run, Delphi runs A, which loads B, and I can debug to my heart's content.

But debugging DLL C is another matter.
It looks like Delphi will only let me debug a DLL loaded directly from the EXE.
But this is a DLL loaded from another DLL.

Is there some way to do this? Thanks.

This is Delphi 7.

Comment: I think modern Delphi debugger lets you debug all the way through no probs.

Comment: Delphi-XE2 has an option to 'Debug spawned processes' under Options|Dubugger Options|Embarcadero Debuggers.  Does Delphi-7 have this?  Is it 'checked'?  Have you tried setting Run|Params for DLL C to A.EXE?

Comment: Another thought, you might be able to load the symbol table after the DLL C is loaded.  XE2 has a debug 'Modules' window where you can right-click a module and force it to reload the symbol table, as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12707464/822072 -- perhaps Delph-7 has the same?

Comment: James L.,   "Debug spawned processes"  did the trick. Thank you.  I never knew that was there before.  If you'll put that in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Are you sure you can't open DLL "C" in the Delphi IDE and set it's "host" as A.Exe? I really doubt Delphi cares much about how the DLL's are loaded, direct or indirect. I'd look for the problem somewhere else, maybe your "B" DLL is loading a different "C" DLL from a different location, maybe you're not setting the brakepoints in routines that are being called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the "Debug spawned processes" check box.

In Delphi 7, this is under Tools | Debugger Options | General.

In Delphi XE-2 and XE-5 it is found under Tools | Options | Debugger Options | Embarcadero Debuggers.

Comment: This answer was given by James L. in a comment to the original post, but he declined to post it as an answer.  I put the answer here to make it easier for future visitors to find it.

Comment: @ david - people like you make stackoverflow better!