# Access Violation when i drop a TidSMTP on a Form

Tags: delphi, indy, access-violation, delphi-xe4

i've a problem with Delphi XE4: when i drop on a form an TIdSmtp or TIsSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL i receive this error:

```
[511EDABF]{IndySystem180.bpl} IdStack.TIdStack.IncUsage (Line 688, "IdStack.pas" + 11) + $7
[511EEBB2]{IndySystem180.bpl} IdComponent.TIdComponent.InitComponent (Line 229, "IdComponent.pas" + 1) + $5
[50EE84A2]{IndyCore180.bpl} IdTCPConnection.TIdTCPConnection.InitComponent (Line 912, "IdTCPConnection.pas" + 1) + $2
[50EE0D99]{IndyCore180.bpl} IdTCPClient.TIdTCPClientCustom.InitComponent (Line 256, "IdTCPClient.pas" + 1) + $2
[50FC53D5]{IndyProtocols180.bpl} IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase.TIdExplicitTLSClient.InitComponent (Line 262, "IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase.pas" + 1) + $2
[50FC8E5D]{IndyProtocols180.bpl} IdMessageClient.TIdMessageClient.InitComponent (Line 643, "IdMessageClient.pas" + 1) + $2
[510B9AF9]{IndyProtocols180.bpl} IdSMTPBase.TIdSMTPBase.InitComponent (Line 193, "IdSMTPBase.pas" + 1) + $2
[510BB47D]{IndyProtocols180.bpl} IdSMTP.TIdSMTP.InitComponent (Line 383, "IdSMTP.pas" + 1) + $2
[511CF547]{IndySystem180.bpl} IdBaseComponent.TIdInitializerComponent.Create (Line 186, "IdBaseComponent.pas" + 4) + $4
[21D64B2B]{delphicoreide180.bpl} CompPalMgr.TComponentPalettePageItemDelegate.CreateComponent (Line 2756, "CompPalMgr.pas" + 2) + $7
[2113FFAB]{designide180.bpl} ComponentDesigner.TComponentRoot.DoCreateComponent (Line 2359, "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 12) + $17
[21145796]{designide180.bpl} ComponentDesigner.TComponentRoot.CreateCurrentComponent (Line 4450, "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 2) + $32
[2115DBAA]{designide180.bpl} Surface.TDesignSurface.CreateItem (Line 195, "Surface.pas" + 1) + $11
[2111193A]{designide180.bpl} Designer.TDesigner.DoDragCreate (Line 794, "Designer.pas" + 1) + $F
[211121E8]{designide180.bpl} Designer.TDesigner.DragEnd (Line 974, "Designer.pas" + 19) + $3
[21114880]{designide180.bpl} Designer.TDesigner.MouseUp (Line 1763, "Designer.pas" + 1) + $2
[51FEEE82]{vcldesigner180.bpl} VCLSurface.MouseEvent (Line 3187, "VCLSurface.pas" + 45) + $11
[5005F7EB]{rtl180.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 16933, "System.pas" + 2) + $7
[51FEFA6F]{vcldesigner180.bpl} VCLSurface.TVclDesignSurface.IsDesignMsg (Line 3448, "VCLSurface.pas" + 48) + $6
[50582B07]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.DispatchAction (Line 11494, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 9) + $C
[0B6A7E30]{IDEFixPack.dll} VCLDesignerGuideLinesHideFix.IsDesignMsg + $94
[5045287F]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7137, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 4) + $21
[50170090]{rtl180.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 16860, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[50456DEB]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.IsControlMouseMsg (Line 9807, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 1) + $9
[504575B5]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10039, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 153) + $6
[505777F9]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.WndProc (Line 4388, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 201) + $5
[51FF84BF]{vcldesigner180.bpl} VCLFormContainer.TControlSizer.ControlWndProc (Line 311, "VCLFormContainer.pas" + 33) + $C
[50456BF8]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9751, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[50170090]{rtl180.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 16860, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[50582213]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.CancelHint (Line 11117, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 6) + $E
[50580E87]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 10288, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[50580ECA]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 10318, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[50581205]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 10456, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 26) + $3
```

Anyone can help me?

With other components like IdUserPassProvider or IdSASLPlain work fine.

Regards

Comment: Does this happen if you create a new, empty VCL forms application and drop the component on the new, blank form?

Comment: This is an extremely peculiar issue, and my instincts lead me to believe that possibly some customization may have been done to the Indy library? That is, if Ken's proposed test also fails. Otherwise, if a fresh application causes no issues, then the blame points to the particular project this is being used in. Or possibly an Indy upgrade/downgrade which was unsuccessful?

Comment: Looks like an Indy defect. Specifying version numbers (Delphi and Indy) would be useful. Upgrading to latest Indy might help.

Comment: @KenWhite : yes, i've the same problem with a new project.
i've a suspect that there are some package that i've disabled that cause this error.
I'm investigating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the support, 
I solved the problem but I have not yet understood why.

the problem is in the Design package; I attach the differences between the dproj that working and the dproj with the error.

I still have not figured out if it depends on a single package or more, anyway, enabling all packages work correctly.

Thanks again, 
I go back to replicate if i find the package that generates the error.

[image: differences beetwen working and not working dproj]

Comment: Your solution works. Delete the old Dproj file and let Delphi recreate it (which means the bug in not in Indy but in Delphi).

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to diagnose your problem without seeing the actual error message.  Is it an actual `EAccessViolation` exception, or is it a different type of exception?  Just because an exception is raised does not guarantee it is actually an `EAccessViolation` unless it really is an Access Violation.

`TIdStack.IncUsage()` ensures that Indy's global `GStack` object exists. That object is what provides access to all of the low-level platform-specific socket API functions used throughout Idny.  `IncUsage()` itself is a `class` method, so it is not called on a `TIdStack` object instance, so merely calling `IncUsage()` itself is not the cause of the exception.

Internally, `IncUsage()` uses three global variables in the `IdStack` unit:

```
GStackCriticalSection: TIdCriticalSection
GInstanceCount: LongWord
GStackClass: TIdStackClass
```

All three variables are initialized to `0`/`nil` in their respective declarations, and then `GStackClass` and `GStackCriticalSection` are assigned/constructed in the `initialization` section of the `IdStack` unit.

An exception can only occur if one of those variables is invalid at the time `IncUsage()` is called (unless the exception is coming from a `TIdStack` constructor, but I do not see that in your call stack).

Perhaps something in your project is preventing the `initialization` from being called, causing `IncUsage()` to crash when it tries to enter the `GStackCriticalSection` lock (but I do not see `TIdCriticalSection.Enter` in your call stack)?  There is an `Assert()` to make sure `GStackCriticalSection` is not `nil` before it is used, but maybe your copy of Indy was compiled with asserts disabled?

Comment: Complete error message is:
Access violation at address 511EDABF in module 'IndySystem180.bpl'. Read of address 14D04428.

Comment: The error msg is: Access violation at address 512FF2AF in module 'IndySystem210.bpl'. Read of address 14144508. Deleting the Dproj file and letting Delphi to regenerate it will solve the problem.