# Is there a limit to the Delphi Win64 debugger loading symbols?

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-10.2-tokyo, win64

I'm using RAD Studio 10.2.3 Tokyo.

**Research**

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50811975/), and [this issue](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20705) I run into trouble when debugging my flagship application that extensively utilizes runtime BPLs as a plugin system.

The problem occurs only when compiled and debugged as a Win64 application, and using Delphi's Win64 internal debugger. Delphi's Win32 internal debugger does not have this problem.

When using "load all symbols" in the debugger options, I miss stack and local symbols info for some units but not other units in the same BPL (check screenshots).

However, when I use the option to load debug info for specific BPLs, and only in my runtime BPL all units have local symbols info. Logically, I am missing debug info for all other units.

Of course, I dont like having to specify each symbol table specifically, I would rather load all symbol tables and not have to mess with it.

I have also experimented with using the symbol tables path, but this made no difference in loading the debugging results.

**Question**

Has anyone else experienced this, and found a better workaround than specifying which symbol tables to load?

Maybe something like an INI file, or Registry setting, or other solution for the Win64 debugger?

**Some background info and screenshots below**

Debugging view when turning on "Load all symbols"

[image: Result when using Load all symbols]

Debugging view when using specific symbol table for this runtime BPL

[image: Result when loading one specific symbol table]

Settings for specific symbol table loading

[image: settings for specific symbol table loading]

Comment: I also found this related issue on the embarcadero site, and in there it was mentioned you can also use wildcards for loading the symbols tables. Ant his works like a charm to work around the problem whthout having to specify each and every bpl that I use. https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-10080